# Dynamically creating properties in C# for use with XmlSerializer

Tags: c#, xml, xmlserializer, castle-dynamicproxy

I have an API that accepts xml messages. Suppose I have obtained object Thing from this API which looks like this:

```
<Thing shape="circle" color="red"/>
```

and is mapped to:

```
[XmlRoot("Thing")]
public class Thing {
    [XmlAttribute("shape")]
    public string Shape { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("color")]
    public string Color { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to update this object so that eg. color is green. The API requires me to send it in the following format:

```
<Thing color="green" o_color="red"/>
```

Is there a way to generate o_* properties on the fly? So that when they are set outside of constructor their old value is stored in some generated property that XmlSerializer maps to o_? I know I could simply create those properties manually, but for bigger objects its a tedious work. I've tried to do that with Castle's Dynamic Proxy, which I already use in the project, but it seems it just can't add properties like that (or I haven't found out how to do that)

Comment: And what should happens with the `shape`?

Comment: It should be ommited as it hasn't changed

Comment: `XmlSerializer` will still serialize it, it doesn't care about *changed*, only properties with values matching to `DefaultValueAttribute` will be omitted. So, how exactly are you serializing to do not have `shape`? If you don't yet, then the answer is simple: you have 2 problems, which can be solved by making `AnotherThing` to serialize what you want

Comment: You're right, I forgot about it. Out of pure curiosity - what if the shape could be sent anyway? Is there a faster way to have this functionality instead of creating AnotherThing which has both Color and O_Color?

Comment: How does your class work?  Does it have the original value for modified properties cached somewhere?  You might be able to use [`[XmlAnyAttributeAttribute]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlanyattributeattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) along the lines of [How to deserialize element with list of attributes in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32884364) -- but the details depend on how the old value is cached, if at all.

Comment: Based on a [comment in this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393335/is-it-possible-to-add-a-property-to-a-type-via-a-dynamicproxy), I don't think this is possible out-of-the-box.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of issues that need to be solved here. The fist is you must maintain state in each of your serialized objects that will tell you if a property has been altered, and what its original value is. Then your second problem is you need to build a new object dynamically based on this maintained state. With the implementation I provide you will need to determine if it meets your performance needs as it is doing a lot of Reflection. You will also have to weight its complexity with other solutions. The advantage I see with this solution is not having to maintain two very similar object.

**!! Important !!**  This code is not Production ready. I have left a few todos in the code that need to be flushed out.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Reflection.Emit;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public abstract class PropertyStateTracker
    {
        private class PropertyDetails
        {
            public object CurrentValue { get; set; }
            public bool HasChanged { get; set; }
            public object OriginalValue { get; set; }
        }

        private readonly Dictionary<string, PropertyDetails> propertyState =
            new Dictionary<string, PropertyDetails>();

        protected TProperty Get<TProperty>(Expression<Func<TProperty>> propertySelector)
        {
            string name = GetNameFromExpression(propertySelector);
            PropertyDetails data;
            if (!propertyState.TryGetValue(name, out data))
            {
                Set(propertySelector, default(TProperty));
                return default(TProperty);
            }
            return (TProperty)data.CurrentValue;
        }

        protected void Set<TProperty>(Expression<Func<TProperty>> propertySelector, TProperty value)
        {
            string name = GetNameFromExpression(propertySelector);
            PropertyDetails data;
            if (!propertyState.TryGetValue(name, out data))
            {
                data = new PropertyDetails() { OriginalValue = value, CurrentValue = value, HasChanged = false };
                propertyState[name] = data;
            }
            else
            {
                data.CurrentValue = value;
                data.HasChanged = true;
            }
        }

        [XmlIgnore]
        public IEnumerable<string> ChangedProperties
        {
            get
            {
                foreach (var property in propertyState)
                {
                    if (property.Value.HasChanged)
                    {
                        yield return property.Key;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public bool HasChanged<TProperty>(Expression<Func<TProperty>> propertySelector)
        {
            string name = GetNameFromExpression(propertySelector);
            return HasChanged(name);
        }

        public bool HasChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            EnsurePropertyExists(propertyName);
            PropertyDetails data;
            if (!propertyState.TryGetValue(propertyName, out data))
            {
                return false;
            }
            return data.HasChanged;
        }

        public TProperty GetOriginalValue<TProperty>(Expression<Func<TProperty>> propertySelector)
        {
            string name = GetNameFromExpression(propertySelector);
            return (TProperty)GetOriginalValue(name);
        }

        public object GetOriginalValue(string propertyName)
        {
            EnsurePropertyExists(propertyName);
            PropertyDetails data;
            if (!propertyState.TryGetValue(propertyName, out data))
            {
                return GetDefaultValue(GetPropertyInfo(propertyName).PropertyType);
            }
            return data.OriginalValue;
        }

        public TProperty GetCurrentValue<TProperty>(Expression<Func<TProperty>> propertySelector)
        {
            string name = GetNameFromExpression(propertySelector);
            return (TProperty)GetCurrentValue(name);
        }

        public object GetCurrentValue(string propertyName)
        {
            EnsurePropertyExists(propertyName);
            PropertyDetails data;
            if (!propertyState.TryGetValue(propertyName, out data))
            {
                return GetDefaultValue(GetPropertyInfo(propertyName).PropertyType);
            }
            return data.CurrentValue;
        }

        public void Reset()
        {
            foreach (var property in propertyState)
            {
                property.Value.OriginalValue = property.Value.CurrentValue;
                property.Value.HasChanged = false;
            }
        }

        private void EnsurePropertyExists(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyInfo property = GetPropertyInfo(propertyName);
            if (property == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("A property named '{0}' was not found for type '{1}'",
                    propertyName, this.GetType().Name));
            }
        }

        private PropertyInfo GetPropertyInfo(string propertyName)
        {
            Type type = this.GetType();

            var property = type.GetProperty(propertyName, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.IgnoreCase);
            return property;
        }

        private static object GetDefaultValue(Type t)
        {
            if (t.IsValueType)
                return Activator.CreateInstance(t);

            return null;
        }

        private static string GetNameFromExpression<TMember>(Expression<Func<TMember>> lambda)
        {
            // check to make sure a non-null lambda was provided.
            if (lambda == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("lambda");
            }

            Expression expression = lambda.Body;

            // is the expression's body a unary expression.
            var unaryExpression = expression as UnaryExpression;
            if (unaryExpression != null && unaryExpression.NodeType == ExpressionType.Convert)
            {
                expression = unaryExpression.Operand;
            }

            // is the expression's body a parameter expression.
            var parameterExpression = expression as ParameterExpression;
            if (parameterExpression != null)
            {
                return parameterExpression.Name;
            }

            // is the expression's body a member expression.
            var memberExpression = expression as MemberExpression;
            if (memberExpression != null)
            {
                return memberExpression.Member.Name;
            }

            // is the expression's body a method call expression.
            var methodCallExpression = expression as MethodCallExpression;
            if (methodCallExpression != null)
            {
                return methodCallExpression.Method.Name;
            }

            // unable to derive name. throw an exception.
            throw new Exception(
                string.Format("Failed to derive name from expression '{0}'",
                expression));
        }
    }



    [XmlRoot("Thing")]
    public class Thing : PropertyStateTracker
    {
        [XmlAttribute("shape")]
        public string Shape
        {
            get { return Get(() => Shape); }
            set { Set(() => Shape, value); }
        }

        [XmlAttribute("color")]
        public string Color
        {
            get { return Get(() => Color); }
            set { Set(() => Color, value); }
        }
    }


    class Program
    {

        private static long count = 0;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Thing thingInstance;
            System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Thing));
            string rawData = "<Thing shape=\"circle\" color=\"red\"/>";
            using (System.IO.StringReader reader = new System.IO.StringReader(rawData))
            {
                thingInstance = (Thing)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
            }

            thingInstance.Color = "green";

            // these two variables should be reused every time a new proxy is created. you dont want too many dynamic assemblies.
            var assemblyBuilder = AssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicAssembly(new AssemblyName("DynamicThingAssembly"), AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);
            var moduleBuilder = assemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule("DynamicThingModule");

            // TODO: need to figure out a way to reuse the proxyTypes being generated or you will have a 
            // memory leak. the type is unique based on the properties that have been modified, so you should be able to use 
            // the state stored inside of thingInstance to figure this out. I leave this up to you to implement.
            Type proxyType = CreateProxy(moduleBuilder, thingInstance);
            var proxy = Activator.CreateInstance(proxyType);

            foreach (var propertyName in thingInstance.ChangedProperties)
            {

                proxyType.GetProperty(propertyName, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.IgnoreCase)
                    .SetValue(proxy, thingInstance.GetCurrentValue(propertyName));
                proxyType.GetProperty("O_" + propertyName, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.IgnoreCase)
                    .SetValue(proxy, thingInstance.GetOriginalValue(propertyName));
            }

            // Important this XmlSerializer should be cached, otherwise you will have a memory leak in your program.
            System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer serializer2 = new XmlSerializer(proxyType, new XmlRootAttribute("Thing"));

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            using (System.IO.StringWriter writer = new System.IO.StringWriter(sb))
            {
                serializer2.Serialize(writer, proxy);
            }

            Console.Write(sb.ToString());
        }

        private static Type CreateProxy(ModuleBuilder moduleBuilder, Thing thing)
        {
            var typeName = "DynamicType" + System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment(ref count).ToString("X5");
            TypeBuilder typeBuilder = moduleBuilder.DefineType(typeName, TypeAttributes.Public);

            Type t = typeof(Thing);
            foreach (var propertyName in thing.ChangedProperties)
            {
                var propertyInfo = t.GetProperty(propertyName,
                    BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.IgnoreCase);

                CreateProperty(typeBuilder, propertyInfo.Name, propertyInfo.PropertyType);
                CreateProperty(typeBuilder, "O_" + propertyInfo.Name, propertyInfo.PropertyType);
            }

            return typeBuilder.CreateType();
        }

        private static void CreateProperty(TypeBuilder typeBuilder, string propertyName, Type propertyType)
        {
            var fieldBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineField("_" + propertyName, propertyType, FieldAttributes.Private);

            // The last argument of DefineProperty is null, because the
            // property has no parameters. (If you don't specify null, you must
            // specify an array of Type objects. For a parameterless property,
            // use an array with no elements: new Type[] {})
            var propertyBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineProperty(
                propertyName, PropertyAttributes.HasDefault, propertyType, null);


            var attributeConstructor = typeof(XmlAttributeAttribute).GetConstructor(new Type[] { typeof(string) });
            propertyBuilder.SetCustomAttribute(
                new CustomAttributeBuilder(
                    attributeConstructor,
                    new object[] { propertyName.ToLower() }));


            // The property set and property get methods require a special
            // set of attributes.
            MethodAttributes getSetAttr =
                MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.SpecialName | MethodAttributes.HideBySig;


            MethodBuilder getPropertyMethodBuilder =
                typeBuilder.DefineMethod("get_" + propertyName,
                                  getSetAttr,
                                  propertyType,
                                  Type.EmptyTypes);

            // Create the get methods body.
            ILGenerator getPropertyMethodILGenerator = getPropertyMethodBuilder.GetILGenerator();
            getPropertyMethodILGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
            getPropertyMethodILGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, fieldBuilder);
            getPropertyMethodILGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);


            // Define the "set" accessor method for CustomerName.
            MethodBuilder setPropertyMethodBuilder =
                typeBuilder.DefineMethod("set_" + propertyName,
                                           getSetAttr,
                                           null,
                                           new Type[] { propertyType });

            // Create the set methods body.
            ILGenerator setPropertyMethodILGenerator = setPropertyMethodBuilder.GetILGenerator();
            setPropertyMethodILGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
            setPropertyMethodILGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
            setPropertyMethodILGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, fieldBuilder);
            setPropertyMethodILGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

            // Last, we must map the two methods created above to our PropertyBuilder to 
            // their corresponding behaviors, "get" and "set" respectively. 
            propertyBuilder.SetGetMethod(getPropertyMethodBuilder);
            propertyBuilder.SetSetMethod(setPropertyMethodBuilder);



        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How do you like this approach?

```
Thing thing;
var xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Thing));
thing = (Thing)xs.Deserialize(inputStream);

// Stored the old value in the property that will not be used.
thing.Shape = thing.Color;

thing.Color = "green"; // set new value

// Rename unused Shape property to o_color
var attributes = new XmlAttributes { XmlAttribute = new XmlAttributeAttribute("o_color") };
var overrides = new XmlAttributeOverrides();
overrides.Add(typeof(Thing), "Shape", attributes);

xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Thing), overrides);
xs.Serialize(outputStream, thing);
```

The `Color` property is used for its intended purpose: to store the new color value.

While the `Shape` property that is not returned in your example back, we use for the previous color value are pre-renamed it.

Of course, this is only work in this exceptional case: the data types match.